# Force all applications to use system proxy in macOS Sierra

Tags: proxy, macos

I am forced to use the company's proxy, but some applications (apps) like Cisco VPN Client, Adobe, and others don't use system proxy, and I can't configure proxy settings in apps.

Is any way to force that alls apps use system proxy?

Comment: "I'm under proxy company,..."?  Unclear what you are asking! Maybe: you are forced to use the company's proxy...?

Comment: Ok, I am forced yo use the company's proxy

Answer (score 1):

By default, applications that don't have a build-in option to configure proxy settings will automatically use the system proxy. However, for certain applications (like Terminal), no proxy will be used. If you want to have a system-wide proxy that can't be circumvented, take a look at "Proxifier". It uses a kext or a system extension (depending on the version of the application) to route all network traffic through it. You can configure proxies and rules inside the application. Note that for the version with system extension, some network traffic from Apple services will be able to circumvent Proxifier; this is determined arbitrarily by Apple.

I'm not sure why you would want to use a proxy for Adobe or a VPN client. Adobe softwares generally don't require the internet to work, while VPN client connects you to a proxy.

Comment: An alternative is proxyCap which handles socks and ssh proxies and dns over tunnel.